# On submitting a form with React Hook Form and redirecting to a new page, how can I pass the form data to that page?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have a Submit function that currently works well. After submission, I can successfully redirect to a page, let's say "Thank you." However, I want to pass the submitted data to that redirected page as parameters. How can I achieve this?

This is my form:

```
  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<ValidationSchema> = async (data) => {
    try {
      if (!isValid) {
        console.error("Form is invalid:", errors)
        return
      }

      const typeTitles = { project: "Een project starten", "contact-question": "Een vraag stellen" }
      const isQuestionType = currentType === "contact-question"

      const formData = {
        ...data,
        ...(isQuestionType ? {} : { budget: `${values[0]} - ${values[1]}K` }),
        type: typeTitles[currentType],
        categories: selectedValues
      }

      const response = await fetch("/api/send", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData)
      })

      const result = await response.json()

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Failed to submit form. Status: ${response.status}`)
      }

      if (response.status === 200) {
        // showSuccessToast()

        console.log("Form data:", formData)

        toast.success(
          `Hey, ${formData.firstName} Bedankt voor je bericht! We nemen zo snel mogelijk contact met je op.`
        )

        // reset({ firstName: "", company: "", projectDetails: "", email: "" })
        setCurrentType("project")
        setValues([4, 10])
        setSelectedValues([])

        router.push({
          pathname: "/bedankt",
          query: { formData: JSON.stringify(formData) }
        } as any)

        return result
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error submitting form:", error)
    }
  }
```

This is my page of redirect:

```
"use client"

// Import the useRouter hook from Next.js
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation"

// In your functional component
const BedanktPage = (props) => {
  const router = useRouter()

  console.log(props)

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="text-4xl font-micro-medium text-center pt-24 pb-12">
        Yo bedankt voorje bericht.
      </h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default BedanktPage
```

I have tried console logging the props. but its empty.